# Como faço herança de uma classe abstrata em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas, método-abstrato

Em Java temos a possibilidade de criarmos classes abstratas, mais sem a possibilidade de instanciá-las, porém podemos criar e instanciar uma classe que herde os atributos e os métodos de uma progenitora abstrata. Em C++ isso é feito de uma forma diferente e eu gostaria de saber como se faz?

Até agora eu tentei fazer oque foi dito acima (ou quase), criar uma classe abstrata e herda seu atributos e métodos para outra classe que será instanciável. Segue o código:

Mother.h

```
#ifndef MOTHER_H_INCLUDED
#define MOTHER_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

typedef std::string str;

class Mother{

    private:

        str test01;
        str test02;

        unsigned test03;

    public:

        virtual void setTest01(str teste01_)=0;
        virtual void setTest02(str teste02_)=0;

        virtual void setTest03(unsigned teste03_)=0;

    public:

        virtual str getTest01()=0;
        virtual str getTest02()=0;

        virtual unsigned getTest03()=0;

};

#endif // MOTHER_H_INCLUDED

//Red Hat
```

Mother.cpp

```
#include "Mother.h"

void Mother::setTest01(str test01_){

    test01=test01_;
}

void Mother::setTest02(str test02_){

    test02=test02_;
}

void Mother::setTest03(unsigned test03_){

    test03=test03_;
}

str Mother::getTest01(){

    return test01;
}

str Mother::getTest02(){

    return test02;
}

unsigned Mother::getTest03(){

    return test03;
}
```

Daughter.h

```
#ifndef DAUGHTER_H_INCLUDED
#define DAUGHTER_H_INCLUDED

#include "Mother.h"

class Daughter: virtual public Mother{



};

#endif // DAUGHTER_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Mother.h"
#include "Daughter.h"

int main(void){

    Daughter tst;

    return 0;
}
```

Quando compilo o programa com o GNU g++:

> error: cannot declare variable ‘tst’ to be of abstract type ‘Daughter’
>   Daughter.h|6|note: because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Daughter’:|

...entre outros erros e avisos

Comment: A ideia de ter métodos abstratos na classe base é para que eles não tenham implementação nessa classe base e apenas nas classes derivadas. Já para não falar que é bem incomum um getter ou setter ser abstrato.

Comment: @Isac Vivendo e aprendendo! não sabia desse negocio de getter e setter ser incomum como abstratos. Obrigado pelo seu comentário.

Comment: @Isac "A ideia de ter métodos abstratos na classe base é para que eles não tenham implementação nessa classe base e apenas nas classes derivadas." - Então no caso estou incorreto ao implementar minha classe base abstrata em um arquivo .cpp?

Comment: Seria incorreto, a ideia é não implementar na base. Se vai implementar na classe base então não os coloque abstratos, retirando o `=0` em cada um deles.

Comment: @Isac Blz! Então eu vou implementar na Daughter.h? Mais como faço isso?

Comment: Não no seu caso faria sentido deixar a implementação na `Mother.h` mas sem ser abstrata, porque dificilmente iria querer dar outra implementação diferente na classe derivada. Mas é um pouco de difícil perceber o que pretende fazer num exemplo tão exotérico.

Comment: @Isac Cara...mais o negocio aqui não é se faz sentido e sim eu saber como eu vou fazer a herança de uma classe abstrata, não é atoa que o nome das variáveis tem "test" pra todo lado.

Answer (score 2):

Discordo do comentário que diz que *getters/setters* abstratos são incomuns. Na verdade em C++ o mecanismo de *getters/setters* são incomuns, mas onde eles são usados é comum o uso, se fizer sentido, a classe ser realmente abstrata, o que muitas vezes não faz, aí nem seria caso incomum, seria errado.

Concordo totalmente que um exemplo de classe com nomes abstratos e sem uma definição clara do que o objeto é não dá para modelar nada direito. O que pode ser certo para um caso pode ser muito errado para outro. Se fizer algo que não faz sentido então está errado e não deve fazer.

Tanto o Isac quanto eu e vários outros usuários aqui temos o compromisso de ensinar certo, podemos errar, mas tentamos acertar o tempo todo. Seria irresponsável de nossa parte aceitar algo errado tendo conhecimento que está. Então tem algumas soluções dependendo do que é o objeto.

## Classe abstrata

A classe não é abstrata ou pelo menos parte dela não é abstrata (sim, é possível ter uma parte abstrata e outra não, claro que a classe será considerada abstrata e não instalável com apenas um método abstrato, mas o resto dela não precisa ser abstrato:

```
class Mother {
    string test01;
    int test03;
    public:
        virtual string getTest01();
        virtual void setTest01(string teste01);
        virtual int getTest03();
        virtual void setTest03(int teste03);
};

string Mother::getTest01() { return test01; }
void Mother::setTest01(string test01) { this.test01 = test01; }
int Mother::getTest03() { return test03; }
void Mother::setTest03(int test03) { this.test03 = test03; }
```

#### Daughter.h

```
class Daughter: virtual public Mother {}; //só faz sentido se fizer mais alguma coisa
```

## Interface

Se quer que os métodos sejam abstratos não faz sentido ter atributos, então podemos transformar esta classe um uma interface:

```
class Mother {
    public:
        virtual string getTest01() = 0;
        virtual void setTest01(string teste01) = 0;
        virtual int getTest03() = 0;
        virtual void setTest03(int teste03) = 0;
};
```

#### Daughter.h

```
class Daughter: virtual public Mother {}; //não muito, mas aqui até faz sentido

string Daughter::getTest01() { return test01; }
void Daughter::setTest01(string test01) { this.test01 = test01; }
int Daughter::getTest03() { return test03; }
void Daughter::setTest03(int test03) { this.test03 = test03; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/AbstractXInterface.cpp)

Simplifiquei porque se é um exemplo abstrato não tem porque colocar mais que o mínimo necessário. Eu poderia ter tirado o `Teste03`, não o fiz para mostrar que uso do `int` (quase sempre o uso do `unsigned` é um erro e quando não é costuma-se usar `unsigned int` (programar para você entender entender é fácil, para todos entenderem é mais difícil). Usei-o também para mostrar que costuma-se agrupar os método pelo que eles são e não pelo que eles fazem. Tem que deixar próximo o que está relacionado.

E ainda usei `string` porque aquele `typedef` só serve para causar problemas de legibilidade e comer algum erro sem querer.

Claro que eu tirei partes do código que não são necessários para o entendimento do problema já que é um exemplo abstrato demais.

Não fiz um exemplo de classe abstrata (no lugar de uma interface) porque o exemplo é abstrato demais, mas seria possível ter atributos em casos onde faça sentido (não este).

Fiz outras melhorias cosméticas, mas importantes.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre colocar a função somente como virtual e colocar como virtual porém com um "=0" no final?

Comment: `virtual` deixa a função ser sobrescrita, `= 0` faz ela não ter implementação.

Comment: Ok, nesse caso não fazeria sentido colocar '=0' no final de uma função virtual caso queira implentar essa função em outra classe???

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: Desculpa! Confundi as bolas. O'que eu queria dizer é se por a caso quando colocamos '=0' no final de uma função estamos dizendo para ela ser um metódo final?

Comment: Não, é exatamente o oposto disto, algo que não tem uma implementação jamais poderá ser `final`, ainda que isto não exista em C++.

Comment: Em C++ uma classe abstrata pode conter logica(código)?

Comment: Está demonstrado na resposta.